# Snap-To lines when aligning controls at Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, canvas, lines

I have an app where users can drag controls around on a Form. But they
re asking me for Snap-To lines to make the alignment of controls easier. I have no idea about the snep-to lines and how to implement them - I have looked at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752100.aspx Adorner's, but it says it's only for WPF. And I tried it in WinForms but (as expected) didn't work.

How can I get snap-to lines (something like the ones in VS) in my app?

Thank you

Bael

Answer (score 1):

In your move control you could adjust the `Left` and `Top` by dividing and then multiplying by the width of your lines:

```
left = (left/10)*10;
top = (top/10)*10;
```

It's not perfect but it it simple. Of course since controls don't have a MoveEnd event you'll have to track the MouseButton state or something similiar.

**Edit:** A better implementation would properly round the division results so 134 = 130 and 136 = 140.

Comment: Um... That looks to simple to be true :P Thanks for that Cory, I'm gonna see what I can do :)

Comment: Often times the best solutions are the simplest :-). I didn't implement this code so I'm very anxious to hear how the idea has (or has not) worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'm still looking for a solution ; here is what I did so far, it could be a solution for you

```
const grid = 12;
private void MyControl_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Left % grid != 0)
        this.Left -= this.Left % grid;
    if (this.Top % grid != 0)
        this.Top -= this.Top % grid;
}
```

or in a usercontrol

```
protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Left % grid != 0)
        this.Left -= this.Left % grid;
    if (this.Top % grid != 0)
        this.Top -= this.Top % grid;
}
```

My current challenge is the drawing activity; my controls are hosted in a panel, I am looking for a way to lock and unlock that panel drawing when necessary; for example: only after left or top changed

Comment: This solution will work perfectly if you're moving controls through the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` events instead of `SendMessage`